# Windows App 8.1 StackPanel Mouse-Over

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1, mouseover, stackpanel

I have a `StackPanel` on a Windows 8.1 app and I want to add a `Mouse-Over` function.
If I understand correctly the similar function on Windows 8.1 apps is `PointerEntered/PointerExited`. How can I get the "Item's" text of a `TextBlock` for example with those functions?

EDIT: I basically want to get the `TextBlock`'s handle when mouse is over it so I can get or set it's properties(text etc...).

This is my `C#` function

```
private void itemGridView_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

and my xaml code:

```
<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="120,126,120,50"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" PointerEntered="itemGridView_PointerEntered">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="110" Width="480" Margin="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                            <Image x:Name="ImageItemName" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemTitleText" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ItemDescText" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <GridView.Header>
            <StackPanel Width="480" Margin="0,4,14,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Margin="0,0,0,20" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                <Image x:Name="imageName" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="400" Margin="0,0,0,20" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="DescTextBlock" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridView.Header>
        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="52,0,0,2"/>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use property `Children`  to getting a `UIElementCollection` of child elements.

[Panel.Children property. MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    private void StackPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var values = new List<string>();
        var sp = sender as StackPanel;
        if (sp != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in sp.Children)
            {
                var tb = child as TextBlock;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    values.Add(tb.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's a very good answer and answers a big part of my problem. I have a simple question. What happens with an Image? I tried creating a new child as Image and then get the Images.Properties but none was avaible.

Comment: I simply replaced `var tb = child as TextBlock;` with `var tb = child as Image;`. Tried to get the Image of the `StackPanel`. All properties where available but all returned `null`

Comment: Because your stackpanel have no `Image` element, you can add it , `var newImage = new Image(); sp.Children.Add(newImage);`

Comment: God, I feel really bad. I updated xaml code. Check the `Image` named `ImageItemName`. That's the `Image`'s properties I want to get on mouse hover. My mistake, I didn't realise it was not in the stack panel